# How to find Exact String Match in Python?

Tags: python

I have list of words and want to check if string contains any of words from a list.

The code

```
String : "Business communication is often termed as the lifeblood of business concern justify this statement with an example"  
words = ['Fortnite', 'Digital Games',"Business","Technology","periodic table","med","ments"] 
for s in Q:
    s=re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+'," ",s)

    print(s)
    for k in words:
        if k.lower() in s: 
            print(k)
```

Results: Business, med

Expected Output: Business

Comment: This is not reproduceable

Comment: The list of word is  words = ['Fortnite', 'Digital Games',"Business","Technology","periodic table","med","ments"]

Comment: @Peter what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
string = " " + inputString + " "
for word in words:
    if (" " + word + " ") in string:
        print(word)
```

Adding spaces in condition prevents problems with sub-words like `med`. First line allows first and last word to be found. If you need to deal with commas and periods then additional coding is required.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
words = ['Fortnite', 'Digital Games',"Business","Technology","periodictable","med","ments"]
inputString = "Business communication is often termed as the lifeblood of business concern justify this statement with an example"
for word in words:
    for string in inputString.split(' '):
        if word == string:
            print(word)
```

It's computationally expensive, but it seems like it will do what you want it to do. Your regex string is nowhere near complicated enough to search for the words you want it to search for.

Comment: This one returns both Business and Med. Where as I am looking for exact match of String not the subset of string.

Comment: I modified the answer.

Comment: No this one doesnt work either. the Split() Splits the words in String I have some words in words list with more than 2 words in it. e.g periodic table (By mistake it has connected together) here, is any Input String has Periodic table in it I want the program to return Exact match "Periodic table".

Answer (score 0):

Given `words` and `inputString`:

```
words = ['Fortnite', 'Digital Games',"Business","Technology","periodictable","med","ments"]
inputString = "Business communication is often termed as the lifeblood of business concern justify this statement with an example"
```

you can create sets and take the intersection:

```
wset = set(words)
inpset = set(inputString.split())
print(wset & inpset)
```

which prints

```
{'Business'}
```

Comment: No this one doesnt work either. the Split() Splits the words in String I have some words in words list with more than 2 words in it. e.g periodic table (By mistake it has connected together) here, is any Input String has Periodic table in it I want the program to return Exact match "Periodic table".